# Converting T-SQL to SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am trying to convert the T-sql to SAS. I have the following code in T-Sql

```
(Right(POpener.ObligorNumber,10)+ Right('00000'+Cast(Cast(BalLoc.CommitmentNumber as Int)as varchar(5)),5)) as 'Key'

Case when blf.AnnualRate <> 0 then Cast(blf.AnnualRate as Varchar(7))  
when blf.Amount <> 0 then 'F' + Cast(CAST(blf.amount as Int)AS varchar(7)) else 'WAIVE' End  as Pricing
```

and I converted it into SAS code as :

```
cat(put(input(POpener.ObligorNumber,best10.),z10.),put(input(BalLoc.CommitmentNumber,best10.),Z10.)) as Key

Case 
when blf.AnnualRate NE 0 then put(blf.AnnualRate,z7.)
when blf.Amount NE 0.00 then cats('F',put(blf.amount,z7.))
else 'WAIVE'
End as Pricing
```

I am not getting the desired output. Can anyone tell me what is the mistake in my code?

Thank you,

Shankar

Comment: Are both calculations not working? And are there errors or just not what you want?

Comment: @Reeza: The code runs well but I am not getting the desired value.

Comment: What are you getting versus what do you want? Can you show us some sample input vs output data?